# Beautifulsoup: How do I get the text from a webpage into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the date value into a dataframe using beautifulsoup.

I want to get "17 May 2021"

How can I do it?

My existing code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

urls = {
    "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"
}
class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []

def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'table-matches'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    if main is None:
        return None
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[0].text
    league = count[1].text
```

[image: Inspect element for text value]

How can I get the date value in `df`?

Comment: So have you able to find date or just want to create a data frame with that date??

Comment: I have a dataframe which is from this page. I want the date appended to the dataframe. Also, if I can convert it to a datetime object, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am uncertain about your use of class here, whether all functions are part of it, whether df is actually the shape & contents you intended, and you certainly need to return df. That aside, to answer your exact question, inside the second function, put this at the end:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(soup.select_one('#col-content h1').text.split(', ')[-1],'%d %b %Y') #.date()
df['date'] = date
```

And remember to `import datetime`.

Comment: Apologies to get your attention here however can you pease help me [answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058259/scraping-oddsportal-for-matches-and-odds) The website changed yesterday and I would need to rewrite the scraper and I am requesting your help in his regards.